Is there an add-on that gives you the analytical surfaces/equations of the geometry?
I would really appreciate some help on this. I have a slightly imperfect hemisphere, and I want to be able to derive the analytical equations that make it up. Is there a Blender add-on that does this? If not, is there an external program that can do this? If the program could give the analytical equations, that would be great, but providing the analytical surfaces that make up the geometry could work as well. I have tried importing the .stl file of my imperfect hemisphere to Matlab to try to derive information from it, but I am not sure if that could lead anywhere in terms of eventually deriving the analytical equations that make up the imperfect hemisphere. I have searched for add-ons or programs that can do this with no luck. Once again, any help is appreciated! Thank you for taking the time to read this.
Update: Here is the blender file I am using:


Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? GeometryNodes could be useful (and enough), if the underlying "analytical equations" are classical parametrisation of hemispheres.

Hi, Thank you so much for your response! I have updated my post to include the Blender file I am using. How could I go about using GeometryNodes to extract the equations? Thank you once again, StefLAncien.

Do you manufacture this case for the demonstration, or is it the only hemisphere you would like to "identify" ? Because the deformation is quite simple in this case : X coordinate is scaled by 60/57.2 and Z coordinate is offset by 0.75. I found this information mostly reading the Transform>Dimensions panel after I applied all transformations. But if you are looking for a more general procedure, could we assume that the mesh looks like half a UV sphere for all cases ?

Hello, StefLAncien! This is a simple case that we are using to try to extract the analytical equations. We would like the apply the program/add-on to work with more complex models such as the tip of a cone or a specific region of a large cylindrical shape. Extracting the analytical equations would make it easier to process the needed parts of the model using a Python script. Hopefully, that makes sense. Thank you once again for your help!
